# DataGridView - возрастающая последовательность в строке

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется два `DataGridView`. Надо сделать так, что если в первой матрице имеется строка, которая вся идет по возрастанию, то она должна копироваться во вторую матрицу. Я пытался сделать это так `if (matA[i, j] < matA[i, j+1])`. Если выполняется, то записывается в массив. Но дело в том, что последний столбец отбрасывается. Так что прошу помочь с этим.

Вот код,вывожу в массив,а не в матрицу для проверки. Столбцы и строки задаю с помощью numericUpDown.

```
rivate void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = matrA.RowCount;
        int m = matrA.ColumnCount;
        int[,] matA = new int[n, m];
        int[] mas = new int[m];
        int i, j;
        bool b = false;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                matA[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(matrA[j, i].Value);

        for (j = 0; j < matrB.ColumnCount; j++)
            matrB[j, 0].Value = j + 1;



        i = 1;
        while (i < n)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < m - 1; j++)
            {
                if (matA[i, j] < matA[i, j + 1])
                {
                    mas[j] = matA[i, j];

                    int c1 = mas.Length;
                    if (c1 == m)
                    {
                        b = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (b == true)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {

                textBox1.AppendText(mas[j] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: можете показать ваш код

Comment: Написал ответ, должно работать. Если есть вопросы - спрашивайте, попробую помочь :)

Comment: Благодарю,смог разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Ваш алгоритм неправильный. Вам нужно проверить каждую строку матрицы по отдельности. Тут удобнее вместо прямоугольного массива использовать массив массивов, тогда вы сможете естественно работать со строкой матрицы.

Для проверки образуют ли элементы массива возрастающую последовательность вы можете использовать такой метод:

```
    bool isUpp(int[] arr)
    {
        if (arr == null || arr.Length == 1)
            return false;

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
            if (arr[i] <= arr[i - 1])
                return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Тогда для отбора нужных вам строк из матрицы достаточно будет написать:

```
var onlyUpp = data.Where(isUpp).ToArray();
```

Пример:

```
    int[][] Fill(int n, int m, int max = 20)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return
            Enumerable.Range(0, n)
                .Select(_ =>
                    Enumerable.Range(0, m)
                    .Select(__ => rand.Next(max))
                    .ToArray())
               .ToArray(); 

    }

    bool isUpp(int[] arr)
    {
        if (arr == null || arr.Length == 1)
            return false;

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
            if (arr[i] <= arr[i - 1])
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        int m = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
        if (n < 1 || m < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("N, M должны быть >= 2; ");
            return;
        }
        var data = Fill(n, m);
        var onlyUpp = data.Where(isUpp).ToArray();

        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.RowCount = n;
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = m;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                dataGridView1[j, i].Value = data[i][j];

        dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
        int k = onlyUpp.Length;
        if (k == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Строка образующую возрастающую последовательность не обнаружена");
            return;
        }
        dataGridView2.RowCount = k;
        dataGridView2.ColumnCount = m;

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                dataGridView2[j, i].Value = onlyUpp[i][j];
    }
```